Description Resource Path Location Type The type org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject cannot be resolved
I try to create adynamic petri net using petri net markable language framework (PNML) using java, in eclipse IDE and maven project dependency ,I use PNML documentation code to export to PNML file , on exporting step always error appear:
enter image description here
could you kindly help me to solve problem please:
1-Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject. Fix the build path then try building this project   PNML_Test       Unknown Java Problem
2--Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
The type org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type fr.lip6.move.pnml.framework.utils.ModelRepository Test.java   /PNML_Test/src  line 1  Java Problem
I try to use HLAPI documentation to solve problem using link:
https://pnml.lip6.fr/pnmlframework/apidocs/fr/lip6/move/pnml/framework/utils/ModelRepository.html#createDocumentWorkspace-java.lang.String-
put I confused about VoidRepositoryException ?

maybe you should read and consider the answer to Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a read of the [ask] section of the [help]. I would also recommend you take the [tour]. While the error in text format is included in the question, it needs to be formatted properly. But [mre] is missing altogether.

There's a lot more to say about this subject, and about how to ask a question on SO.
But the solution you are looking boils down to this: your project needs to be a "Plug-in Project" and not a "Java Project". This allows you in the MANIFEST, in tab "dependencies", to add a dependency to bundle "org.eclipse.emf.ecore".
